# Como incrementar um JSON.stringify dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando montar um JSON.stringify de forma dinâmica.

Exemplo:

valor inicial : `var body = JSON.stringify({ "UserName": email });`

```
if(input1Change != 0){
    if(input1 != ""){
        //incrementar o JSON.stringify
    }
}else if(input2Change != 0){
    if(input2 != ""){
        //incrementar o JSON.stringify
    }
}else if(input3Change != 0){
    if(input3 != ""){
        //incrementar o JSON.stringify
    }
}else if(input4Change != 0){
    if(input4 != ""){
        //incrementar o JSON.stringify
    }
}else if(input5Change != 0){
    if(input5 != ""){
        //incrementar o JSON.stringify
    }
}else if(input6Change != 0){
    if(input6 != ""){
        //incrementar o JSON.stringify
    }
}
```

Objetivo:

```
var body = JSON.stringify({ "UserName": email, "Name": input1.value, "Surname": input2.value, "DateBirth": d, "MobilePhone": input4.value });
```

Comment: Por que não altera o próprio objeto e utilizar o `JSON.stringify` apenas no final?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Levi, creio que se você alterar o objeto `obj` e apenas utilizar o método `JSON.stringify` resolva o seu problema. Acho que incremetar o `JSON.stringify` não seria uma boa ideia pelo fato de que o retorno dele é uma string. Sugiro fazer algo parecido com o abaixo:

**JS:**

```
var obj = {}

obj.Nome = 'Nome'

if(true){
    obj.UserName = 'Nome'
}

if(false){
    obj.Telefone = '(00) 0000-0000'
} else {
    obj.Telefone2 = '(00) 0000-0000'
}

var body = JSON.stringify(obj)

console.log(body)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso de **n** formas, mas tudo depende de como você espera sua saída:

```
   var ObjUser = {
       UserName:"",
       Name:"",
       Surname:"",
       DateBirth:"",
       MobilePhone:""
    }

    if (input1Change != 0 && input1 != "") {
      ObjUser.UserName = input1;
    }
    if (input2Change != 0 && input2 != "") {
      ObjUser.Name = input2;
    }
    //...etc


    var body = JSON.stringify(ObjUser);
```